# Everything is crashing on first boot 14.04

Tags: boot, nvidia

Today I installed Linux on my PC that used to have Windows 10. The hard drive was completely wiped and then I installed Ubuntu. At first, my gpu driver was not working for my GTX 970, so I did the nomodeset thing and booted into Ubuntu. I am currently in Ubuntu, but everything crashes when I try to open it. Everything useful, that is.
My main problem is that whenever I go into software and updates section in the settings page, then go to additional drivers, it crashes. Not the OS, it just closes and asks if I would like to send a crash report and all that.
I am very mildly experienced with Linux, and I have never encountered this.
Also, if I search drivers and I click on the "Additional Drivers" it crashes instantly, unlike if I go into the settings and click on the software and go into additional drivers, then it will search for a second or two AND THEN crash.
I am lost. I have already tried editing the SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py and corrected the spelling error on license, but it did not work.
Any help is appreciated to get this fixed and get the drivers for my gtx 970 installed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352-updates
```

This will install the official Nvidia drivers (and probably fix all of your issues).

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I installed chrome because Firefox is not working, and now it is all good. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I just remembered something. I need to get Firefox running because I am using this machine for a science fair project where I need multiple browsers. How can I fix the Firefox crash?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install firefox`

Comment: After running the command, go to "Additional Drivers" again and install any other drivers that need installation.

Comment: @Zakocsm If this was the solution to your question, please click the checkmark on the left to thank the user and allow others to easily find the information